# Sum of k natural numbers in terms of two other functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $n_1$, $n_2$, $\dots$ $n_k$ are given natural numbers. Can we write the addition $\sum$ of these $k$ numbers in terms two other functions $f$ and $g$?

i.e. $\sum(n_1, n_2,\dots,n_k)=f(n_1, n_2,\dots,n_k)+g(n_1, n_2,\dots,n_k)$?

Clearly, the addition function needs $k-1$ steps to add the $k$ given natural numbers. But if we are able to get the functions $f$ and $g$ in such a manner that $f$ and $g$ can be evaluated for the $k$ numbers in one shot then addition of k number can be computed in two three steps.

Any help is highly solicited.

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

$$f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = x_1+x_2+\cdots x_n\\
g(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n) = 0$$

means that the sum of $f$ and $g$ gives you the sum of the natural numbers input.

---

I don't really understand, however, how you would like to sum up $k$ natural numbers in two or three steps, especially as $k$ becomes large. It is reasonable to expect that for larger values of $k$, it will become more difficult (will take more steps) to calculate the sum of $k$ numbers.

Comment: You gave most trivial answer and the function f cannot be evaluated  in one shot.

Comment: Essential aim is to derive two other functions in such a manner that the time complexity can be reduced for addition when k is large.

Comment: @SkSarifHassan 2 points. One, you asked for 2 functions that will result in the sum of the input values. I provided them. Two, yes, my answer is trivial and in the second part of my answer, I explained to you that finding a function that can be evaluated in "one shot" is impossible, as summing $k$ numbers is more difficult for larger values of $k$.

Comment: Professor, do you mean there does not exists any functions $f$ and $g$ such that the complexity is get reduced?

Comment: I am not a professor, and I am not saying that, I am just saying that the complexity will not be constant (you clearly want it to be constant)

Comment: Well. My aim is to reduce derive the infimum complexity. So in this case the complexity would be constant as infimum would be unique.

Comment: I am far from certain, but I think that in order to sum $k$ numbers, you have no other choice but to perform $k-1$ operations.

Comment: You mean $k-1$ is the infimum. Am I right? Could you please prove it if you claim so?

Comment: As I said, I do not *know* that $k-1$ is the infimum, it is just my educated guess. I have no way to prove it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. Let us look for other answers by mathematicians in this regard.